# How can I multiply a INumber<T> with an int?

Tags: c#, math, numbers, .net-7.0, .net-generic-math

How should I implement the multiplication by int (`z * 2`) on the last line?

```
public static TResult Test<TResult>() where TResult : INumber<TResult>
{
    TResult x = TResult.AdditiveIdentity;
    TResult y = TResult.MultiplicativeIdentity;
    TResult z = x * y;
    TResult z2 = z * 2; // <--- this gives the CS0019 error "The operator * cannot be applied to operands of type 'TResult' and 'int'
    return z2;
}
```

--- the suggested solution is to add an interface, but it breaks this:
`IMultiplyOperators<TResult, int, TResult>`

```
public static void Tester()
{
    Test<decimal>(); // CS0315 Tye type decimal cannot be used as type parameter TResult..... there is no boxing conversion
}
```

For now I will inject the function myself and use:

```
public static TResult Test<TResult>(Func<TResult, int, TResult> mul) where TResult : INumber<TResult>
{
    TResult x = TResult.AdditiveIdentity;
    TResult y = TResult.MultiplicativeIdentity;
    TResult z = x * y;
    TResult z2 = mul(z, 2);
    return z2;
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I suggest [converting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.inumberbase-1.createchecked?view=net-7.0) `2` to `TResult` and only then multiply:

```
   TResult z2 = z * TResult.CreateChecked(2);
```

Here we create `TResult` instance from integer value `2`, while *checking* `2` for overflow and similar possible errors (an exception will be thrown if `2` can't be converted into `TResult`: either `OverflowException` or `NotSupportedException`).

**Code:**

```
public static TResult Test<TResult>() where TResult : INumber<TResult>
{
    TResult x = TResult.AdditiveIdentity;
    TResult y = TResult.MultiplicativeIdentity;
    TResult z = x * y;
    TResult z2 = z * TResult.CreateChecked(2);
    return z2;
}
```

**Demo:**

```
Console.WriteLine(Test<decimal>());
```

**Output:**

```
0
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Cs0rto)

Comment: I wander if there could have been an interface that supports the implicit converters int to TResult.

Comment: @Wouter - implicit conversions should always be safe. How are you so confident in your belief/assertion that `2` can always be converted into *any* domain in which maths will be performed such that an *implict* conversion should exist instead of an explicit one?

Comment: I mean like adding an interface `IImplicitConvert<int, TResult>` if decimal implements it the conversion doesn't need the 'CreateCheck' which is just a big switch and isn't really polymorphic/type safe.

Answer (score 16):

You need to add the `IMultiplyOperators<, ,>` interface:

```cs
public static TResult Test<TResult>() where TResult : INumber<TResult>, IMultiplyOperators<TResult, int, TResult>
{
    TResult x = TResult.AdditiveIdentity;
    TResult y = TResult.MultiplicativeIdentity;
    TResult z = x * y;
    TResult z2 = z * 2;
    return z2;
}
```

You can see the list of operator interfaces [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/math#operator-interfaces).

Comment: Althoug this does work. Look at decimal.cs it doesn't implement the `IMultiplyOperators<TResult, int, TResult>`  interface only `IMultiplyOperators<decimal,decimal,decimal>`

Comment: @Wouter I'm afraid I don't actually know the solution for decimal in that case. A simple solution that would work for multiplying by 2 would be just to add `z` to itself, but that definitely wouldn't scale. Another approach might be to convert integer 2 to `TResult` using `Convert.ChangeType`, but I kind of feel that defeats the point of generic maths slightly, so I'm not sure.

Comment: indeed 2 was just an example (could have added z + z).  Maybe there is an interface to do the (implicit) conversion?

Comment: Injection of `Func<TResult, int, TResult> multiply` to this function will work.

Answer (score 6):

While not a general solution, in this very case (multiplier = 2) you can simply write:

```cs
TResult z2 = z + z;
```

Except the z is TResult.AdditiveIdentity * TResult.MultiplicativeIdentity. But TResult.AdditiveIdentity is zero. So the result will be zero.

Comment: More generally, multiplication by _any_ integer can be mathematically defined (and, if desired, implemented) in terms of repeated addition (and possibly negation). In practice you'd want to implement something like the [peasant multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peasant_multiplication) algorithm, which can multiply a number by an integer *n* using only O(log *n*) additions (and some integer bit manipulation). Of course the result of this may or may not match the behavior of "native" integer multiplication, although for reasonably sane number types it really should.

Comment: It was a minimal example it shows that multiplication is working on TResult. Next what about multiplying it by a float / double. or even another INumber? `public static void Test<X, Y>(X x, Y y) where X : INumber<X> where Y : INumber<Y> => Console.WriteLine(x * y);`